# Python: Iterating through tuples which are related as subclassed tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following tuples:

```
ReadElement = namedtuple('ReadElement', 'address value size')
LookupElement = namedtuple('LookupElement', ReadElement._fields[0:2] + ('lookups', ReadElement._fields[2]))
```

and I want to iterate through them as follows:

```
mytuples = [ReadElement(1,2,3), LookupElement(1,2,3,4)]
for address, value, lookups?, size in mytuples
    if lookups is not None:
        addLookups(lookups)
    print address, value, lookups?, size

def addLookups(*items):
    return sum(items)
```

How could I iterate through similar tuples using the same piece of code?

I think what I am looking for is a Union type of the two named tuples, so that that union type preserves the order of the tuples in the loop.

From laike9m post I can see how I can use the isinstance operator without having to unpack the tuples in the loop however I would like to avoid special casing the data and just go straight through without any if statements.

If these were objects I could do something like mytuples[0].execute() without having to worry about what type they were as long as they were were subclassed from the same parent and had that method implemented.

It seems that my question maybe a variant of the following [Why are Super-class and Sub-class reversed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304341/why-are-super-class-and-sub-class-reversed) . In the case above I only have two items one subclass and one superclass where they are very similar to each other and therefore could also be made into a single class.

Comment: Your namedtuples don't look like they are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your namedtuple definition is wrong, should be:

```
LookupElement = namedtuple('LookupElement', ReadElement._fields[0:2] + ('lookups', ReadElement._fields[2]))
```

Second, you don't need to do worry about all that:

```
>>> for nt in mytuples:
    print(nt)


ReadElement(address=1, value=2, size=3)
LookupElement(address=1, value=2, lookups=3, size=4)
```

I'm going to sleep so maybe I can't answer your futher question. I think the best way is to check whether the field you want exists before using it.

I don't know exactly what you want, here's what I'll do:

```
mytuples = [ReadElement(1,2,3), LookupElement(1,2,3,4)]
for nt in mytuples
    if 'lookups' in nt._fields:
        print nt.address, nt.value, nt.lookups, nt.size
    else:
        print nt.address, nt.value, nt.size
```

Comment: Thanks @Iaike9m I fixed the answer to reflect the corrected LookupElement, the print sample I have given is a trivial example. If I wanted to perform certain manipulations on the data that these tuples required I would not be able to reference them by nt. Ill add in an example in the question to clarify this

Comment: I don't think that python has anything like this inbuilt. It is similar to a BNF style grammar idea whereby a rule can be represented by tokens which may or may not be present (optional). In this case its the superset/union properties of (ReadElement and LookupElement) -> address, value, lookups?, size

Comment: @Har Python has something similar when getting return value from a function. `(ReadElement and LookupElement) -> address, value, lookups?, size` is impossible AFAIK. But why do you need such thing? If you want all elements in tuples, you could use `list(some_named_tuple)`, if you want to use selected elements, just access them by name.

Comment: Since the operations on these two types of tuples are similar I wanted a way to concatenate them and simplified the operation by saying as long as you have tuples of this type you dont need to worry about individual naming. I guess its a form of pattern matching that I wanted. I think the solution you have provided is the way forward as there is no language builtin for this, it must be manually crafted.