# Subset vs Subtyping in OOP

Tags: oop, inheritance, subtyping

If 'A' is a subtype of 'B', it means that 'A' inherits all the fields and methods of 'B' and in addition to that 'A' has it's own methods and fields. So 'A' should be considered to be a superset of 'B'? How is the subset interpretation of subtyping valid? Shouldn't it be the vice versa?

But again if there are two classes 'Cars' and 'Vehicles', it makes sense that the set of 'Cars' is a subset of the set of 'Vehicles'. However the fields and methods of 'Cars' is a superset of 'Vehicles'. So I'm a bit confused regarding this.

Comment: Superset of fields, subset of instances I'd say.

Comment: This question has more thorough answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304341/6651650

Answer (score 1):

There was once some controversy over which should be the "sub" in the relationship. That's one of the main reasons C++ uses the terms "base class" and "derived class" instead of "super class" and "sub class." Stroustrup wanted to avoid the whole question.

But to mirror what @usr said in the comments, the terminology war has settled down over the years and it is generally accepted that the "subset of instances" denotes a "subclass".