# Does TypeScript inheritance violate the substitution principle in OOP?

Tags: typescript, oop

As far as I know, a derived class in OOP languages is typically a superset of its base class. Meaning that derived class should add more things instead of removing things from base class.

Only if a language follows this principle, type-casting a derived class instance to base class will function correctly.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case in TypeScript. The types of properties in base class can only be narrower in derived class, and it's really weird.

The following code is allowed in TypeScript, but it certainly causes problems:

```js
class BaseClass1 {
    value!: number | string;
}

class DerivedClass1 extends BaseClass1 {
    moreValue!: string; // apparently, adding more properties is allowed
    declare value: number; // type narrowing
}

let baseInstance: BaseClass1 = new DerivedClass1();
baseInstance.value = "hello"; // it is allowed in typescirpt, but definitely wrong
```

This piece of code feels good, but TypeScript says it's wrong:

```js
class BaseClass2 {
    value!: number;
}

class DerivedClass2 extends BaseClass2 {
    declare value: number | string; // wrong! can't be wider
}
```

Do I have the wrong understanding of OOP? Or if my understanding is right, and TypeScript does violate the principle, I'd like to know why it decided to work this way.

I think if the type of a base class property in derived class becomes wider, but the methods in base class only consider the narrower type in base class, calling base class method in derived class will cause problems. But still, it seems TypeScript is in a dilemma.

Comment: TypeScript is kinda inconsistent on covariance/contravariance. There is no explicit syntax for it, so TypeScript tends to accept more than what should be allowed, arguing that this leniency makes it more useful on real-world code. If subtyping were to be strict, you'd only be allowed to narrow `readonly` properties, widen only writeonly properties, and not override the type of normal properties at all.

Comment: A property is writable _and readable_. So although it's OK that the subtype has a wider property type from a writing perspective (anything that sets `thing.value = 123` is still fine), it's a problem from a _reading_ perspective (anything that does `1 + thing.value` is in trouble if it's a string).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank u so much, it's indeed a problem regarding readable and writable. Looks like Typescript is just not very strict.

Comment: @algConfused - You can violate the Liskov Substitution Principle in most languages, it's a matter of how easy or hard it is. Granted, your example here is surprising (at least to me), but TypeScript has the herculean task of applying a layer of type information on top of the wild west of JavaScript code. There are several "pragmatic" choices involved where a pure solution from a type perspective just won't work, because of that unique challenge. :-)

Comment: `As far as I know, a derived class in OOP languages is typically a superset of its base class.` - that is wrong - it is the opposite way. But it seems to confuse people: [Why are Super-class and Sub-class reversed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304341/why-are-super-class-and-sub-class-reversed)

Comment: TS's type system more or less assumes that properties are to be read and not written. This is obviously not the case, but it's much closer to reality than the reverse, which is what you seem to want.  If TS allowed you to widen subclass properties then you'd immediately run into problems merely *looking at* their properties under the substitution principle.  Anyway if I were to write an answer here it would look like [this one about array covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922930/2887218). I'm not going to close this as a duplicate or anything, but I want to at least link it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what my fellow community mates said in the comments, TypeScript has this cool thing called structural typing. Instead of being strict about class hierarchies, it checks types based on their structure. In the first example, it lets you narrow the type of a property in the derived class, which might feel different from traditional OOP.

As the first example you decide to make type more specific as `number`. TypeScript allows this because it priorities flexibility, making it easier for developers to extend classes or fine-tune types.

However, in the second example, TypeScript puts its foot down. If the derived class tries to widen the type beyond what the base class defined, like going from `number` to `number | string`, TypeScript says, "Hold up, that's not cool!" This is to maintain type safety and stick to the agreement set by the base class.

So, TypeScript's approach is all about being adaptable, aligning with the dynamic nature of JavaScript, and finding a sweet spot between static typing and OOP traditions.

**Update>**

Apology for completely ignoring the title of your question.

The TypeScript approach to inheritance aligns with the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP), a fundamental concept in OOP. LSP states that objects of a base class should be replaceable with objects of its derived class without affecting the correctness of the program. In TypeScript, while it allows flexibility in narrowing types for specific scenarios, it doesn't violate the LSP because it maintains the fundamental contract established by the base class.

So, TypeScript's structural typing enhances adaptability without breaking the essential principles of inheritance. You get the benefits of dynamic adjustments while staying within the boundaries of substitution, making it a win-win for flexibility and OOP principles.

Answer (score -1):

1. I don't see why this is wrong. According to the substitution principle, you should be able to assign sub-classes of the type that the variable accepts. You define `value` as `number | string` (either string or number), hence assignments of string is perfectly valid according to TS and according to the substitution principle.
2. this is a wrong statement as TS compiler already told you and it is still in compliance with the substitution principle. You're stating that the variable previously defined as `string` can now be either `string` or `number`. `number` does not extend `string`, hence even according to the substitution principle that would not be a correct thing to do.
   Note however that the following implementation is correct

```js
class A {
    value!: number;
}

class B extends A {
    declare value: number & string;
}
```

this is because the `value` in `B` is forced to define all properties of `number` which is required by `A` and then it adds the string properties on top. Then again, it would be rather difficult for you to define a value that is both a string and a number in the same time.

It is rather difficult to explain the substitution principle on the union types, because when it was originally written, it was meant for languages that didn't support union types - namely Java.
But basically, what the principle says is that you should be able to do the following:

```js
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C {
    value!: A;
}

const x = new C();
x.value = new A();
x.value = new B();
```

and that works.